# Html content in mail body is getting empty in out look mail client after switching to MS Exchange

Tags: c#-4.0, outlook, exchange-server

We are generating a .msg file using following code

```
mailMessage.HtmlBody = strBody;// Here we have html content
var filename = Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath + "/documents/email.msg");
MapiMessage outlookMsg = MapiMessage.FromMailMessage(mailMessage);
outlookMsg.Save(filename);
```

After saving .msg file we are manually opening it using outlook mail client. It opens fine with all html content in the mail body.
But on sending the mail to recipient, the mail body doesn't have the html content in it.
This started happening on switching outlook to MS Exchange, it used to work fine before.
Can any one please help in resolving this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the recipient have html message format turned off?

Comment: What is MapiMessage? Is  mailMessage an instance of Outklook.MailItem?

Comment: @sairam - see if recipient turned off html message as Nilesh said.   Still if you have issue please check this like , https://technet.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/jj983438(v=exchg.150).aspx might help ful to you. I don't think this solution, I'm not much familiar with ms-exchange but I heard

Comment: I suggest that link because to cross check the format for your mail protocol which you used